# angularjs: how to watch a global variable change?

Tags: angularjs

I want to watch the `myApp.myUser` changes:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="js/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="users" ng-controller="usersController">
    <h4>usersController</h4>
    test = {{myUser}}
    </div>        
    <div id="tasks" ng-controller="tasksController">
    <button ng-click="clickMe()">cliquez ici </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and app2.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.users = {};
myApp.tasks = {};
myApp.myUser = {id:1, username:'john'}

myApp.controller('usersController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myUser = myApp.myUser;
    $scope.$watch(myApp.myUser, $scope.userChanged);
    $scope.userChanged = function() {
        console.log('userChanged');
    }   
});

myApp.controller('tasksController', function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = myApp.tasks;
    $scope.clickMe = function() {
        myApp.myUser = {id:2, username:'jack'}
    }
});
```

I tried that with console:

```
myApp.myUser = {id:2, username:'jack'}
```

Nothing.
Then I tried to pass that through the AngularJS with `tasksController`

```
$scope.clickMe = function() {
    myApp.myUser = {id:2, username:'jack'}
}
```

Nothing changes on my view!

http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the variables by declaring it in a service as

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.factory('DataService',function(){
      var myUser ={id:1, username:'john'};
      var tasks;
      var users;
      return{
      users:users,
      tasks:tasks,
      myUser:myUser
      }
    });
    myApp.controller('usersController', function($scope,DataService) {
        $scope.myUser = DataService.myUser;
        console.log(DataService.myUser);   
       $scope.$watch(DataService.myUser, $scope.userChanged);
        $scope.userChanged = function() {
            console.log('userChanged');
        }   
    });

    myApp.controller('tasksController', function($scope,DataService) {
        $scope.tasks = DataService.tasks;
        $scope.clickMe = function() {
            DataService.myUser = {id:2, username:'jack'}
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use properties on your `myApp` variable, that literally holds all of the AngularJS functionality, and you risk collisions.

You have a couple options for storing data in AngularJS:

1. `$rootScope` - Operates just like `$scope`, but is attached to the whole app, not just the current controller.
2. [Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). This is the preferred method, because it keeps your code modular and reusable. In your case, you could set up a data service.

That would look something like...

```
myApp.factory('dataService', function() {
    // this is simplified for illustration, see edit below
    return {
        myUser: {id: 1, username: 'john'},
    };
});

myApp.controller('usersController', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.myUser = dataService.myUser;
});
```

---

**EDIT:**
As discussed in comments, this brings up another potential binding issue, since I used a literal value that can be overwritten via `userService.myUser = {};`. A better data service, which would provide more reliable 2-way binding, would look like:

```
myApp.factory('dataService', function() {
    var users = [
        { id: 1, username: 'john' }
    ];

    return {
        getUser: function(id) {
            for (i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
                if (users[i].id === id) {
                    return users[i];
                }
            }
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('usersController', function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.myUser = dataService.getUser(1);
});
```

Comment: I agree, but also want to urge anyone reading this Q&A to be careful with assignment operations in JS. This example caches a reference with the line `$scope.myUser = userService.myUser`, which is *totally fine*, but only as long as any code manipulating `userService.myUser` does not change the reference value of `userService.myUser` (e.g. `userService.myUser = {id: 2, username: 'jane'};`).

Comment: @JesseAmano, you're correct. I used a simple example to illustrate the point here, but a better solution would involve setting the object *before* the  `return` statement, and then return getter and setter functions so that the reference remains intact. I added a comment in my answer to mention this.

Comment: Yep! I bring it up mainly because the question (and so far one of the answers) has code which overwrites one object reference with a new object reference, seemingly with the expectation that a watcher that only has the old reference will somehow observe the new reference state.

Comment: Agreed. I updated answer again to explain better, because given the nature of the question, my simplified version could cause further headaches without clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the docs for [$scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), the first argument must be a `watchExpression` - that is, an Angular expression (a `string`) describing what value in `$scope` should be watched.

Your value `myApp.myUser` is not part of `$scope` and cannot be reached by `$watch`. The solution would be to move your object into something like `$scope.myUser` and then call `$scope.$watch('myUser', function() { console.log('userChanged'); });`.

Be warned that:

- `$watch` can be expensive if you set up a lot of watches. You usually want a watch set up for data that your users can manipulate on the view, but not for data that you're directly loading through code.
- If the expression points to an object, `$watch` will only track changes to the reference, so `$scope.myUser = {};` would trigger a listener callback but `$scope.myUser.username = 'jack';` would not. You can pass a third argument `true` to make it check for deep inequality, but this gets even more expensive with complex objects or lots of watches.

Comment: Read the documention more carefully. The `watchExpression` can be either a string or a function. A string is evaluated as an Angular Expression. A function is invoked with `scope` as an argument.

Comment: Fair enough. So they maybe could have passed a function that closes over `myApp.myUser` and returns it. Passing a plain-old-JavaScript-object, though, is still definitely not how `$watch` is meant to be used.

Comment: Agree. The recommended way to share data between sibling controllers is to use a service. And `$watch` *could* use a function provided by a service.